# How to match double quoted strings using php

Tags: php, regex

I need to match double quoted strings inside bigger string like:

```
"foo bar" == ""
```

it should match `"foo bar"` and `""` and for this

```
"foo \" bar" == "\""
```

it should match `"foo \" bar"` and `"\""` so far I have this regex:

```
(?<!\\\\)"(?:\\\\"|[^"])*(?<!\\\\)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pO2sC5/1)

but it ends after first escaped quote. and don't return `"foo \" bar"`.

Comment: you haven't given much context for what these quoted strings do, but the example you've given looks very much like it's some kind of programming expression. If that's the case, you a very likely to be better off using a language parser than regex -- these kinds of things can get extraordinarily complex very quickly and regex tends to really struggle with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I would use this:</strike>

```
(?<!\\)"(?:\\"|[^"])*(?<![^\\]\\)"
```

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nX3hE9/2)

---

`(?<!\\)"(?:(?<!\\)\\"|[^"])*(?<![^\\]\\)"` seems to work

Comment: It fail for `"foo \\" == "bar"` [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nX3hE9/3)

Comment: The fixed regex would be `(?<!\\)"(?:(?<!\\)\\"|[^"])*(?<![^\\]\\)"`

Comment: @jcubic it's not yet perfect: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nX3hE9/4) Thanks for kudos anyway

Comment: I don't care about that last case with comment, so this is ok.

Comment: Better regex that match odd number of escaped quotes `(?<!\\)"(?:(?<!\\)\\"|(?:(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\)"|[^"])*(?<![^\\]\\)"`